# RealmSwift: issue whilst saving relationship objects with primary key

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying out Realm and ObjectMapper.

I have these two models:

```
class User : Object, Mappable {

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }

    dynamic var id : String

    [...]

    func mapping(_ map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
    }

}

class Media, Object,  Mappable {

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }

    dynamic var id : String
    dynamic var owner : VPUser?

    [...]

    func mapping(_ map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        owner <- map["owner"]
    }

}
```

Creating an *User* object is fine (i.e. logging in): the JSON gets mapped correctly and the realm insertion goes fine as well.

The issue arises when I fetch the media remotely.
Each *Media* object contains an user object (**owner**).

This is how the media JSON looks like:

```
{
      "id": "574cd4e6e4b0b7e43219664a",
      "owner": {
          "id": "574cd462e4b0b7e432196644",
       }
}
```

Now, the *User* object with that id may exists already,
therefore I get this exception:

```
Can't set primary key property 'id' to existing value...'
```

Note: I'm using `Realm.create(_, update: true)` to save the media.
I thought it would handle relationships, but it's not doing it by the look of it.

Any clue on how to solve it?
Cheers.

Comment: If pass the `Media` object to `Realm.create(_, update: true)`, the `owner` property will be replaced regardless a value of `id`.  I cannot reproduce the error. Could you show more detail code? What object do you pass to `Realm.create(_, update: true)`?